# Adding api.ai chatbot to my Meteor.js chat application

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have a Meteor.js app similar to this one -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66DH69e-wJ0&t=936s as my first Meteor.js app.

And I have created a API.ai chatbot.

And now I need some guildlines of what should I learn/read to achieve something like this:

> I want a function to send user messages to the api and then posts
>   api's answer into the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question if we don't know any details, but I would suggest to read carefully Meteor tutorial. Depending on frontend library you use:

- [Meteor tutorial for Blaze](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)
- [Meteor tutorial for Angular](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app)
- [Meteor tutorial for React](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app)

If you would like to use other libraries the best place to start is the GitHub repository with Meteor integration for this library. For example [Vue](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor).

Secondly, you should read [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/). You will find here tons of useful tips.

I took a quick look at the video you included and `API.ai`. I guess that you will need [this](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client) node package. Also, take a closer look at **[Methods section](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html)** in Meteor guide. You will need them to use `API.ai` package from your client side. When you work with third-party APIs you should also read about **[HTTP](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)** package.